# What is a Nonvocal Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Nonvocal Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Nonvocal Word™, Vocal Word™
Party, Chore
Rhythm, Song
Unhappy, Ecstatic
Many, Few
Chasm, Junction
Abysmal, Superb
Sky, Ground
Alertly, Annual
```

My first attempt at a puzzle so any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Can you confirm that Many is definitely nonvocal?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Yes. "Many" is a Nonvocal Word™.

Comment: Welp there goes my idea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is a nonvocal word...

> a word containing at least one syllable without vowel letters (one of aeiou)?

Specifically,

> par-TY, RHY-THM, un-hap-PY, ma-NY, cha-SM, a-BYS-mal, SKY, a-lert-LY

while on the other hand,

> chore, song, ec-stat-ic, few, junc-tion, su-perb, ground, an-nu-al

I guessed this because

> Many nonvocal words contain "Y".

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Ack, Sniped!  Well played.

Comment: This is kind of a trick question because many of the examples also exemplify the old rule "and sometimes Y"

Answer (score 11):

**ANSWER 2**

Another weird idea that popped into my head:

> Nonvocal Words™ never contain **E**s **I**s or **O**s, while Vocal Words™ always do.  Thus, A Nonvocal Word™ must NOT contain a letter sung in the vocals of the song 'Old MacDonald' **(E-I-E-I-O).**

---

**ANSWER 1**

This might vary with accent/pronunciation, but to me it seems:

Non-Vocal Words:

> When spoken, are ended by saying the name of a letter 
>
> Par-(T) 
> Rhyth-(M) 
> Unhap-(P) 
> Man-(E) 
> Chas-(M) 
> Abysm-(L) 
> Sk-(I)

Vocal Words do not have this quality.

Comment: I don't end Party with T, I end it with 'E'. And Superb ends in B, and Ground ends in D

Comment: This is not the correct answer, but it is an interesting solution!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil : But, 'Superb' doesn't end by saying the letter B (Bee) nor does 'Ground' end by saying the letter D (Dee) which was what my rule would imply

Comment: @yitzih: Dang. Can you provide a counterexample to help me (and others) find the real rule?

Comment: @TwoBitOperation Uncertain would be a Vocal Word™ and ends with the sound of the letter "N" (Uncert-N)

Comment: @TwoBitOperation Another counterexample would be "Tie" which is also a Vocal Word™ and has an "I" as its ending sound.

Comment: F-(U) definitely breaks the pattern proposed in this answer.

Comment: @yitzih  Added another guess

Comment: @TwoBitOperation That is not the correct answer either, however you are getting closer.

Comment: Ill try to find a counterexample for this guess as well

Comment: Counterexample for Answer 2: "Alertly" is a Nonvocal Word™ while "Annual" is a Vocal Word™

Comment: If you have two separate answers, please post them separately.  It becomes very confusing to have multiple unrelated answers in one post.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Gotcha, new here and wasn't sure which was proper, especially when the forum got all uppity and asked ARE YOU SURE? when I clicked new answer  :-P